# How can I make cards in Material UI appear in a horizontal row?

Tags: material-ui, responsive-design

I’m implementing Material UI in my project.

I have a list of cards... I want them to appear one by one in a horizontal row and then in the same pattern in the next row. But my cards are appearing one below the other.

I have tried adding some custom CSS, but it doesn’t work. Please check out my code. There are like two cards. With the box, I’m able to add some margin to my cards. How to make them appear next to each other?

```javascript
function Blogs() {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

    const handleExpandClick = () => {
        setExpanded(!expanded);
    };

    return (
        <>

        <Box m={6}>
        <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
          <CardHeader
            title="It’s a cocktail o’clock."
            subheader="May 14, 2021"
          />
          <CardMedia
            component="img"
            height="194"
            image="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/selection-various-cocktails-table_140725-2909.jpg?w=2000"
            alt="Paella dish"
          />
          <CardContent>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
            Beat The Heat With Chilled Cocktails At The Best Bars In New York.
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
          <CardActions disableSpacing>
            <ExpandMore
              expand={expanded}
              onClick={handleExpandClick}
              aria-expanded={expanded}
              aria-label="show more"
            >
              <ExpandMoreIcon />
            </ExpandMore>
          </CardActions>
          <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <CardContent>
              <Typography paragraph>To a foodie, summer means one thing and one thing only – DRINKS!</Typography>
              <Typography paragraph>
              Yes people, we know it’s hot out there and the only way to quench your thirst is by guzzling down a bunch of ice-cold cocktails
              </Typography>
              <Typography paragraph>
                <h4>1.The Bar Room at The Beekman</h4>
                Visit the beautiful Bar Room in the historic Beekman Hotel for high-key romance that really wows.
                Do try the whiskey sour.One of the best drinks available.
                <h4>2.Dublin House</h4>
                You can never go wrong with Sláinte! Margarita,Pot O'Gold, & Irish Old Fashioned
              <h4>3.Russian Samovar</h4>
              Alpensahne,Amarula Cream Liqueur, Caribou,Feni
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </Collapse>
        </Card>
        </Box>

        <Box m={6}>
        <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
          <CardHeader
            title="Winner Winner Pizza Dinner"
            subheader="May 14, 2021"
          />
          <CardMedia
            component="img"
            height="194"
            image="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0624/9853/articles/20220211142645-margherita-9920.jpg?crop=center&height=800&v=1660843558&width=800"
            alt="Paella dish"
          />
          <CardContent>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
            Beat The Heat With Chilled Cocktails At The Best Bars In New York.
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
          <CardActions disableSpacing>
            <ExpandMore
              expand={expanded}
              onClick={handleExpandClick}
              aria-expanded={expanded}
              aria-label="show more"
            >
              <ExpandMoreIcon />
            </ExpandMore>
          </CardActions>
          <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <CardContent>
              <Typography paragraph>To a foodie, summer means one thing and one thing only – DRINKS!</Typography>
              <Typography paragraph>
              Yes people, we know it’s hot out there and the only way to quench your thirst is by guzzling down a bunch of ice-cold cocktails
              </Typography>
              <Typography paragraph>
                <h4>1.The Bar Room at The Beekman</h4>
                Visit the beautiful Bar Room in the historic Beekman Hotel for high-key romance that really wows.
                Do try the whiskey sour.One of the best drinks available.
                <h4>2.Dublin House</h4>
                You can never go wrong with Sláinte! Margarita,Pot O'Gold, & Irish Old Fashioned
              <h4>3.Russian Samovar</h4>
              Alpensahne,Amarula Cream Liqueur, Caribou,Feni
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </Collapse>
        </Card>
        </Box>

      </>
    );
}
export default Blogs;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MUI Grid](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/) for responsive layout and horizontal row

```
import { Grid } from "@mui/material"

<Grid container direction="row" justifyContent="center">
   <Grid item xs={4}>
     <Card> ..... </Card>
   </Grid>
   <Grid item xs={4}>
     <Card> ..... </Card>
   </Grid>
   <Grid item xs={4}>
     <Card> ..... </Card>
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

`xs={4}` will display `3` Cards in each row because `12/3 = 4` as MUI uses 12 columns grid system. You can also use `md`, `sm`, `lg`, `xl` for different screen sizes.